# How to import only variables from other py files?

Tags: python, web-scraping, import

Hi I am trying to implement similar document recommendation and search function by scraping news articles.
Below is a py file that loads news articles and stores the information in an array.

```
from daumnews import get_news_daum, get_news_contents_seoulgyeongje
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import os
links, titles = get_news_daum()
```

> #When the get_news_daum() function is executed, links and titles are saved as a list in the links and titles variables.

```
contents = []
similarities = []

os.chdir("C:/Users/hanbonghun/Desktop/newsscrapping/news")
for i in range(len(links)):
    with open(f'{i+1}.txt',"w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        contents.append(get_news_contents_seoulgyeongje(f,links[i]))
```

> #When the get_news_contents_seoulgyeongje() function is executed, the titles and contents of the scraped documents are saved in a specific
> folder, and each contents are saved as a list in the contents
> variable.

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words="english")
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(contents)
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
similarities = pairwise_similarity.toarray()

print("succeeded in reading news articles.\n")
```

> #Part that analyzes the similarity of contents elements

As a result, when you run get_news.py, links and titles are stored in links titles, and contents and similarities are stored in the articles and the similarity of each article. The problem is that I only want to load and use these variables from other py files, but when importing the variables through import, all the contents of get_news.py are executed once, which takes a long time.
Is there a way to get only the variables obtained by executing get_news.py from another file?

Comment: if you will not run code then variable can be empty beacause code can't keep these values in variables - code have to save it in file and you would have to read it from this file. If you don't want to run code in file then put it in function - ie. `main()` and use `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` to run it only when you run script directly and not run when you import it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run code when you import file then put code in function - ie. `main()` - and add

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

and it will run code in `main()` only when you run this script directly `python get_news.py`

---

```
links = None
titles = None

contents = []
similarities = []

def main():
    global links
    global titles 
    
    links, titles = get_news_daum() 

    os.chdir("C:/Users/hanbonghun/Desktop/newsscrapping/news")
    for i in range(len(links)):
        with open(f'{i+1}.txt',"w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
            contents.append(get_news_contents_seoulgyeongje(f,links[i]))

    # ... code ...


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

---

But if you will not run code then variables will be empty.

If you saved values from variables in files then you should create function which read values from file and directly returns values and then you should import this function (not variables) and use it

```
from get_news import read_data_from_file

links, titles, contents, similarities = read_data_from_file()
```

Comment: I've checked the answer now. Sorry for being late.
The answer was very helpful to me. Thank you very much!